# Deserialize json file into an array of objects

Tags: python, json

I have a json file containing NZ regions and towns:

```json
{
    "region": [
        {
            "region_name": "northland",
            "towns": [
                "whangarei",
                "paihia",
                "russel"
            ]
        },
        {
            "region_name": "auckland",
            "towns": [
                "auckland",
                "porirua"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also defined a a Region class to deserialize this file:

```py
class Region:
    def __init__(self):
        self.region_name = ''
        self.towns = []
```

I want to convert the above json file to an array of `Region`, this is what I have tried:

```py
import json

def get_nz_regions():
    with open('location/nz_regions.json') as json_file:
        nz_regions = json.load(json_file)

        # return an array of Region
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```py
d = {
    "region": [
        {
            "region_name": "northland",
            "towns": [
                "whangarei",
                "paihia",
                "russel"
            ]
        },
        {
            "region_name": "auckland",
            "towns": [
                "auckland",
                "porirua"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

class Region:
    def __init__(self, region_name, towns):
        self.region_name = region_name
        self.towns = towns
        
d_deserialized = {"region":[]}
for each_region in d["region"]:
    d_deserialized["region"].append(Region(each_region["region_name"], each_region["towns"]))
    
print(d_deserialized)
```

```
{'region': [<__main__.Region object at 0x0000022344DB3DF0>, <__main__.Region object at 0x0000022344DB3D30>]}
```